# 'flutter run' compiles files that is in different directory

Tags: flutter

I'm in directory A, trying to compile it. Running 'flutter run' shows an exception about different project in different directory.

Not sure whether it's a problem with VS Code or flutter CLI or what. Any way I can force it to compile only on current directory?

[image]

See the above image, see my current directory vs the directory on where the exception happen.

I'm on VS Code.

What I have tried:

- flutter clean
- Deleted flutter's bin/cache folder
- Deleted flutter and dart extension on VS Code, restarted VS Code, reinstalled both extension

Comment: This should force the ```flutter run``` to operate in a specific directory, the -t stands for target. ```flutter run  -t lib/main_dev.dart ``` replace ''lib/main_dev.dart' with your directory

Comment: This is an issue in the latest flutter sdk. your app will run anyway